# How can I find out the size of an index in bytes with a query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

how can I find out the size in bytes an index with a query from kibana? I try some queries but not return a result.

```
GET /my_index_name/_stats
```

or

```
 GET /_cat/indices/my-index_name?v=true&s=index
```

Error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "current license is non-compliant for [security]",
        "license.expired.feature" : "security",
        "suppressed" : [
          {
            "type" : "security_exception",
            "reason" : "current license is non-compliant for [security]",
            "license.expired.feature" : "security"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "current license is non-compliant for [security]",
    "license.expired.feature" : "security",
    "suppressed" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "current license is non-compliant for [security]",
        "license.expired.feature" : "security"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 403
}
```

what can i do to solve this problem please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and restart your node.

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. When I add this line and run the elasticsearch.bat file, it closes immediately. Elasticsearch.bat is not running. I also checked from Kibana and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: What error do you get when starting elasticsearch.bat?

Comment: Can you paste the full output in your question please?

Comment: I am forbidden to make any changes to elasticsearch.yml file. Do you think kibana can solve this problem? @Val

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Thank you for your help. The change to the elasticsearch.yml file worked.